# Serving a static file through AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to **serve a small PNG file** through an AWS Lambda endpoint.

However, I don't think it's possible because I want the file extension in the route. My goal:

```
GET /image.png
```

I do not think I can use AWS S3 because I want to **trigger a function** when they `GET` the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I don't think it's possible because I want the file extension
>   in the route.

You can have  a file extension as part of the API Gateway route. There is no limitation preventing you from doing this.